# How to Create an ISO 8583 sub message

Tags: iso8583, openiso8583.net

I am trying to create a sub message for my ISO 8583 Message
I am using the OpenISO8583.NET library by John Coxley.

My resulting ISO sub message looks like this:
00000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000172013012895943184

What my spec says is that for my sub message I need an 8 byte bitmap, so mine looks like this:
0000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Then a variable length field on position 9 (with a maximum of 17 characters and a 3 digit length indicator) so my value looks like this:

0172013012895943184:

(the 017 is the length indicator then the rest is the value being passed)

However according to the application i am trying to send this message to, my message is incorrect if there is anybody out there that can identify the flaw in my sub message I would appreciate it a MIL thanks.

I've been trying to figure this value out for 2 weeks now.

Comment: above and beyond my attempts this is the value that is populated into the sub field in the response from the application i am attempting to connect with:
$?\0\0\0\0\0\010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011020 \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0

which i have no idea what to make of this. :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about sub-messages in the ISO, but your data is of **length 16**, not 17...